# XDocument with inline schema. SchemaInfo is null

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

OK, so here we go. I've got a set of XML documents that I'm loading into my app. In my little test I've created a reader that validates against the schema specified by the XML document. Using the following code it works quite nicely.

```
// Set the validation settings.
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

// Create the XmlReader object.
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("xml/note.xml", settings);

// Load the XDocument from the reader
XDocument loadedDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Now my XML document gets loaded correctly and any validation errors that occur are handled by the callback.

However, if I want to get schema information about an element by calling GetSchemaInfo() on said element, I'm given null. [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167070/xelement-getschemainfo-is-returning-null-why) talks about using an overloaded Validate method, but that doesn't really apply to this situation, unless I'm missing something.

Is it possible to get the schema info loaded into the XDoc using an inline schema or should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112949/250725) to my own question.

The first paragraph after the code block is what is important to you, but basically, the `SchemaInfo` *will* be there, but it is not added until *after* the validation callback.

The workaround I used was basically this (NOTE: this code was tested and works when loading an XML directly and calling `XDocument.Validate` on an `XmlSchemaSet`, but the premise should be the same or similar with `XmlReader` and inline schemas):

```
List<XElement> errorElements = new List<XElement>();

serializedObject.Validate((sender, args) =>
{
    var exception = (args.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);

    if (exception != null)
    {
        var element = (exception.SourceObject as XElement);

        if (element != null)
            errorElements.Add(element);
     }

});

foreach element in errorElements
{
    var si = element.GetSchemaInfo; 

    // do something with SchemaInfo
}
```

I was only trying to capture `SchemaInfo` for elements, hence the `as` cast and null check, but this should work for other node types like `Attributes` (not tested though, so i could be wrong).

If you are looking to use a specific callback method instead of an anonymous delegate, your `errorElements` will need to be a class level field and you can do what you need to do with it after the validation is complete (again, I will add in the **untested** tag).

```
public class SomeClass
{

    List<XElement> errorElements = new List<XElement>();

    public void Load()
    {

        // Set the validation settings.
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

        // Create the XmlReader object.
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("xml/note.xml", settings);

        // Load the XDocument from the reader
        XDocument loadedDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

        // do something with errorElements

    }

    public void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = (args.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);

        if (exception != null)
        {
            var element = (exception.SourceObject as XElement);

            if (element != null)
                errorElements.Add(element);
         }

    }

}
```

In response to your comment about wanting the `IXSchemaInfo` for *all* nodes, the Schema info is added to the XElement after the validation regardless of whether the node failed or passed, so your requirement would actually be easier since you do not need to keep a list of failed nodes.  You should be able to do this:

```
public void Load()
{

    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("xml/note.xml", settings);

    // Load the XDocument from the reader
    XDocument loadedDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

    foreach (var node in loadedDoc.Descendants())
    {
        var si = node.GetSchemaInfo();
    }

}
```

The above example will only access the `XElement`s in your `XDocument` but it is just to illustrate my point.  Once the loading is complete and the xml is validate, the schema info should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm unable to test as I'm away from my development machine, but will do so as soon as possible. Looking at the code however, this seems as though it would only work for nodes that have errors. What I was aiming for was to load all schema information, preferably for documents that pass the validation. We're going to use that information for some dynamic serialization later on.

Comment: This exact code will only work on nodes with errors since you are only collection the `XElement`s within the validation callback, but the `SchemaInfo` should still be present *after* the validation completes for everything, so you can try to hit it up at that point (I will add another example).

Comment: Sadly using GetSchemaInfo on elements that have been loaded in this manner returns null. The only way I've been able to get schema info loaded for the whole document is to use the overloaded validate method mentioned in the question I referenced initially. 

It's starting to look as though if I want access to all the schema information I'll need to load and validate my documents that way instead. Not impossible, just not ideal. Thank you for your help. Any other ideas would be welcome!